# Installation error when using easy_install

Tags: python, linux, trac

I installed Edgewall Trac0.11 in Linux Mandriva and I need a module setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg for Python2.5.

When I run the following:

```
sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg
```

I get an error:

```
error: Invalid Python installation: 
unable to open /usr/lib/python2.5/config/Makefile (No such file or directory)
```

I do as described here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#downloads

I can specify the installation path:

```
sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg --install-dir /var/setuptool
```

But the same error occurs.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the version of Python you are running? Are you sure its 2.5? Seems quite old.

Comment: You should upgrade your python version, I believe mandriva has rpm for 2.7.x

Comment: Please to not start with such an ancient Trac version! We've 1.0 these days, and you should really start each new application with that, because support for 0.11 is non-existent regarding Trac itself. It's already obsoleted by Trac 0.12 for years. Only plugin support is still strong, still - bound to fade away sooner or later as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One alternative is to try installing the Mandriva package for `setuptools` with:

```
$ yum install python-setuptools
```

Answer (score 0):

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip is better than easy_install, so use it!